# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileDescriptor.setInt$(int) error in Facebook Audience SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, crash, facebook-audience-network

I have integrated Facebook audience SDK

> 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'

in my project. Ad Showing properly in my device during debugging more but it crashing in the live version. Please note proguard is disable. A crash report is as per below.

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileDescriptor.setInt$(int)' on a null object reference**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void java.io.FileDescriptor.setInt$(int)' on a null object reference
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98) 
>   java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:229) 
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:147)
>   com.facebook.ads.internal.v.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
>   com.facebook.ads.internal.v.b.f$e.run(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

I am getting this error in the Facebook Interstitial ad. How to resolve it?

Comment: we cannot help you if you do not show us your code.

Comment: ok I will update my code here

Comment: @JonGoodwin I only got the crash report by Splunk Mint so not able to post logcat and signed apk downloaded from play store working fine in my device. Its random crashing issue in few devices.

Comment: We need more description on how this situation. For instance I want to see the first line that started in Logcat. It has all the errors there.